# cordova-plugin-ionic-webview, can't set cookies with Javascript document.cookie (iOS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, cookies, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview

Cookies sent by backend are stored, but not the ones set by app itself.
The following code:

```
document.cookie = "notified=1; path=/; expires=Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT";
console.log(document.cookie);
```

returns empty string ("").
Angularjs $cookies.put doesn't work either.

Also, in Safari web inspector, localhost cookies list stays empty. This is only in iOS, no issue on Android. Is there any chance to make it work? I tried cordova-plugin-wkwebview-cookie-sync plugin, but it is probably for cookies set by backend, and it didnt help with my issue.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies do not work in ios application using WkWebView, due to some security restrictions. Cookies can only be set by backend. And in IOS even there are some (syncing) issues while setting the cookies from backend. But those issues can be fixed by using the plugin you mentioned.

To be on safe side, I will suggest you to use localStorage and if you want to pass some data to the server, you should pass them as an API payload or you can set those values in the headers. And on the server side, you should pick those values from headers. I've been following this approach.

Comment: Hi. Do you know an alternative fix to this issue? The plugin mentioned on the post is only compatible with iOS11...

Comment: what issue are you facing?